# When streaming a file from a server, the file size on disk is bigger than the total bytes read, what's going on?

Tags: java, file-io, inputstream, outputstream, fileoutputstream

I'm reading a binary file from artifactory. The file size according to artifactory is 34,952,058 bytes, the `totalBytes` counter that's logged after reading is finished is also 34,952,058 bytes. But the file size on disk is 39,426,048 bytes. What's going on?? 
I've tried `BufferedOutputStream`, `FileOutputStream` and `OutputStream`. 
It's the same result every time. What am I missing?
This is what my latest code looks like at the moment:

```
try {
                URL url = new URL(fw.getArtifactoryUrl());
                URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
                in = connection.getInputStream();
                File folder = utils.getFirmwareFolder(null, FirmwareUtils.FIRMWARE_LATEST, true);
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(folder.toString());
                builder.append("/").append(fw.getFileName());
                Path filePath = Paths.get(builder.toString());
                OutputStream out = Files.newOutputStream(filePath);

                int read = 0;
                int totalBytes = 0;

                while ((read = in.read(bytes)) > 0) {
                    totalBytes += read;
                    out.write(bytes);
                    out.flush();
                }
                logger.info("Total bytes read: " + totalBytes);
                in.close();
                out.close();

<<< more code >>>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code reads correctly, but writes incorrectly

```
while ((read = in.read(bytes)) > 0) { // Read amount of bytes
    totalBytes += read;  // Add the correct amount of bytes read to total
    out.write(bytes);    // Write the whole array, no matter how much we read
    out.flush();         // Completely unnecessary, can harm performance
}
```

You need `out.write(bytes, 0, read)` to write only the bytes you've read instead of the whole buffer.

Comment: Thank you! such a silly mistake. It seems I have to  wait a while before I can accept your answer.